# addprintprocessor doesn't work?

Tags: c++, dll, printing, dllimport

I try to install my printprocesssor in my computer but it doesn't work??!!

the code in below:

```
_In_ LPTSTR pPathName;
_In_ LPTSTR pPrintProcessorName;

string strPathName = "HP1100PP.dll";
string strPrintProcessorName = "HP1100PP";

pPathName = (LPWSTR)strPathName.c_str();
pPrintProcessorName = (LPWSTR)strPrintProcessorName.c_str();

int a = AddPrintProcessor(NULL , NULL ,pPathName , pPrintProcessorName);
```

the output of a is 0.

thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: If a Windows API fails you can call GetLastError to get more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your casts to wide char strings, `(LPWSTR)`, don't actually make the strings be wide char strings. Your data is still ANSI and the casts are simply a means to lie to the compiler. Remove those casts. Don't lie to the compiler.

Then the compiler will reject your code because your text is ANSI but the function expects Unicode text. Because you compile targeting Unicode. This is the error that your untruthful casts suppressed. You need to deal with it properly by correcting the type mis-match. So either switch to `wstring` or call `AddPrintProcessorA`. I suggest the former.

I would also suggest not using `TCHAR` and related types. That was useful when you targeted Win98 which did not support Unicode but those days are long gone.